# Relative path for images

Tags: php, symfony, path, relative-path

I have a problem with images path stored in database.

I have a joomla website with article, and in the content there are images path.

I imported the joomla database in my symfony project, everything is fine except the path of the images.

Since the path are in my content and stored like this:

```
<p>this is my image<img src="images/myimg.png"></p>
```

I can't use `{{ asset('images/myimg.png") }}`. The problem is that these are relative paths, for example I put my images in `/web/images`.
When I am in the frontpage of my blog (the url is mydomain.com/news) it works like a charm, I see all the images, but when I am inside an article, (url like this : mydomain.com/news/article/id) it doesn't work cause symfony change the path of the url to mydomain.com/news/article/images/myimg.png and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If your image folder is path is like this :

```
www.mydomain.com/news/images/
```

and your articles are in :

```
www.mydomain.com/news/article
```

then you have to write your path like this in the article:

```
<p>this is my image<img src="../images/myimg.png"></p>
```

I suggest you to place your image folder like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/images/
```

Then you will be able to use the same path across all your pages like this:

```
<p>this is my image<img src="/images/myimg.png"></p>
```

Comment: hello thanks for the answer, but is there a way to work this out without re-writing every single "<img>" in my database ? i placed my images in /web/images/news and add a "/" to one image but it doesn't work.

Comment: it would be at the root of your website not inside of /web 
if you do not want to rewrite them then you have to create /images inside of article folder

Comment: well with symfony2 "/web/" is kinda the root directory

Comment: website isn't online, nevermind i just re-write every <img> ^^ thanks for your help buddy